# How to find a vector field that is perpendicular to the surface?

Tags: vectors, partial-derivative

Im a bit confused with this question.

Lets have the equation $z= x^2 + y^2$

therefore gradient f is perpendicular to surface $f=$ constant.

In my case it would be $(2x,2y,-1)$ is perpendicular to $0$?

Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: This site uses
[MathJax formatting of formulas](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Answer (score 1):

For every pair $x_0, y_0$ the vector $(2x_0,2y_0,-1)$ is perpendicular to the surface $z-x^2-y^2=0$ in the point $(x_0,y_0, x_0^2+y_0^2)$ of the surface.

Comment: To the OP you should be able to verify that $(2x_0,2y_0,-1)$ is normal to the surface at the point $(x_0, y_0,x^2_0+y^2_0)$?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to say is this:

Define $f(x,y,z):=x^2+y^2-z $ so the equation $z = x^2+y^2 $, is just $f(x,y,z)= 0 $ a surface $C$ where $f$ is constantly $0$.

So for each $(x_0,y_0), \ \nabla f (x_0,y_0)=(2x_0,2y_0,-1)$ is perpendicular to the surface in the following sense:

If $\phi(x,y):= (x,y,x^2+y^2)$ then $\phi$ is the parametrization of $C$ and $\nabla f(x_0,y_0) $ is perpendicular to $\Pi $ the  plane tangent to $C$ in $(x_0,y_0)$ ,where $\Pi=\langle \partial_x\phi(x_0,y_0),\partial_y\phi(x_0,y_0)\rangle$ (the linear combinations of the partial derivatives) :

In effect,  $$\nabla f(x_0,y_0)\centerdot \partial_x\phi(x_0,y_0)=(2x_0,2y_0,-1)\centerdot(1,0,2x_0) = 0 $$ and  $$\nabla f(x_0,y_0)\centerdot \partial_x\phi(x_0,y_0)=(2x_0,2y_0,-1)\centerdot(0,1,2y_0) = 0 $$